# Doctrine - Integrity Constraint Violation logic

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I've been reviewing the Integrity constraint violation issues here on Stackoverflow for the past few days trying to resolve this issue, but I'm not having any success deducing the proper doctrine logic.

I have two entities that express a one-to-many and one-to-many relationship, but when I try to add and persist an item I get a insert error:

(in controller)

```
            $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
            $chartnew = $Charts->setChartNo(9999);
            $user->addUserschart($chartnew);
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
```

an exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO charts (chart_no, id_user) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [9999, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_user' cannot be null

```
class Users  implements UserInterface
{

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Charts",cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="charts")
 */
private $userscharts;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->userscharts = new ArrayCollection();
    //parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Add userschart
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Charts $userschart
 *
 * @return Users
 */
public function addUserschart(\AppBundle\Entity\Charts $userschart)
{
    $this->userscharts->add($userschart);

    return $this;
}
.......
}
class Charts
   {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Users", inversedBy="userscharts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id_user")
     */
    private $charts;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="chart_no", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $chartNo;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_user", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $idUser;



/**
 * Set chartNo
 *
 * @param integer $chartNo
 *
 * @return Charts
 */
public function setChartNo($chartNo)
{
    $this->chartNo = $chartNo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get chartNo
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getChartNo()
{
    return $this->chartNo;
}

/**
 * Set idUser
 *
 * @param integer $idUser
 *
 * @return Charts
 */
public function setIdUser($idUser)
{
    $this->idUser = $idUser;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idUser
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getIdUser()
{
    return $this->idUser;
}

/**
 * Set charts
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Users $charts
 *
 * @return Charts
 */
public function setCharts(\AppBundle\Entity\Users $charts = null)
{
    $this->charts = $charts;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get charts
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Users
 */
public function getCharts()
{
    return $this->charts;
}
}
```

Comment: It seems to be clear for the SQL error. `id_user` is `null` and shouldn't be. This mean that you don't pass `$idUser` properly to your form/query, or that `$idUser` is nulll by default when passed down.

Comment: I think the issue, and what I am not understanding, is how and when to inject the user entity into the Chart entity so that Doctrine can form the proper sql statement, as in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123521/doctrine-one-to-many-relationship-wont-save-integrity-constraint-violation